# Relationship between AC, WO, and Zorn's lemma in ZF-Powerset

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, independence-results

In regular ZF, AC, WO, and Zorn's Lemma are equivalent, but every proof I know (of the implication AC -> WO and AC -> Zorn) uses the axiom of choice on the powerset of X (where X is the Set which is to be well-ordered).

My question is, whether or not there is a proof of this equivalence that doesn't use the axiom of choice or whether there is a Model of ZF-Powerset in which AC holds  but the well-ordering principle (or Zorn's Lemma) fails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a classic theorem of Zarach, that it is consistent that ${\sf ZF}^-$ holds with the Axiom of Choice, but not every set can be well-ordered.

> *Zarach, Andrzej*, **Unions of ${\sf ZF}^-$models which are themselves ${\sf ZF}^-$ models**, Logic colloquium ’80, Eur. Summer Meet., Prague 1980, Stud. Logic Found. Math. 108, 315-342 (1982). [ZBL0524.03039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0524.03039).

Comment: In the quoted paper (p.338), Zarach credits Zbigniew Szczepaniak with first having demonstrated in 1979 that in the ZF^- context, the axiom of choice does not imply that every set can be well-ordered; and he acknowledges how Szcepaniak's work relates to his.